# Does removing KieModule from KieRepository release the memory as well?

Tags: drools

I am using an API from Drools - `kieServices.getRepository().removeKieModule(releaseId);`

I wanted to know whether removing `KieModule` from `KieRepository` will release the memory occupied by that `KieModule` too?

Comment: "release memory", why you bothered about memory?

Comment: I am adding/removing multiple KieModule while the server is running. Need to know whether for performing cleanup I just need to call remove API and that will solve the memory leak issue or anything else needs to be done.

Comment: We are facing the same issue removekieModule is not releasing the memory. Did this work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-381) in the kie module earlier, so if you are using a newer version you shouldn't have memory leak, but if using earlier version you can.

Comment: Hi Piyush in latest drools 7.56.0 verison also remove is not clearing the memory used by KieModule.. Any idea on this ?